# How to bring time series data in following format for sequence to sequence prediction

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have data as shown below,

[image]

I want it to be in following format

[image]

Using Python 3 pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) in loop with `f-string`s:

```
#python 3.6+
for i in range(1,5):
    df[f'demand_{i}'] = df['demand'].shift(-i)

#python bellow 3.6
for i in range(1,5):
    df['demand_{}'.format(i)] = df['demand'].shift(-i)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'demand':[4,7,8,3,5,0],

})

for i in range(1,5):
    df['demand_{}'.format(i)] = df['demand'].shift(-i)

print(df)
   demand  demand_1  demand_2  demand_3  demand_4
0       4       7.0       8.0       3.0       5.0
1       7       8.0       3.0       5.0       0.0
2       8       3.0       5.0       0.0       NaN
3       3       5.0       0.0       NaN       NaN
4       5       0.0       NaN       NaN       NaN
5       0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```